Do I need to create a custom authentication handler for my integration tests in .NET if I use KeyCloak in my application?
I'm currently working on a .NET application that uses Keycloak for authentication. For my integration tests, I want to avoid actually connecting to the Keycloak server to keep the tests fast and reliable.
Is it necessary to create a custom authentication handler for my integration tests, or is there an alternative approach to mock or bypass Keycloak authentication? How can I set up my integration tests to handle authentication properly without hitting the Keycloak server?
Any detailed guidance or example code would be greatly appreciated!
